# Large table mapping to another table

Tags: java, sql, oracle, mapping

Let's take this scenario:
I have a considerable amount of large table having around 500 rows and 5cols.
Now based on value of col1 and col2, I want to update the value of col3 in different table.

For ex. col1 col2 col3

```
       a   b   ab
       c   d   cd
       x   y   xy
       .   .   ..
       .   .   ..
       .   .   ..
```

I'd like to take this value of col3 (based on the value of col1 & col2)and store into some different table.

For ex2.   col1      col2    col3

```
         good    fine       nice 

       ample  sufficient  adequate
         .            .            .
         .            .            .
```

Would you please guide me is there any concept in Java or oracle so I can achieve my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

Use a subselect

```
UPDATE targettable t 
set t.targetcol = (select a.col3 FROM tablea a where a.col1 = t.colx and a.col2 = t.coly )
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but this is not the exact scenario. I have just added that as an example only-otherwise there's a string.
col1      col2           col3
good     fine           nice
ample   sufficient  adequate

Comment: Are we talking about Database tables? What do you mean with 'based on'?

Comment: Yes Turo, Taliking about database tables. By means 'based on'- I'm getting some values, which I'm supposed to compare with the col1 and col2- based on that I'd choose col3's value

Comment: do 'some values' come from the target table? I changed my answer supposing that...

Answer (score 0):

Like that?

```
/* CREATE TABLE exampl1 AS (SELECT 'a' AS a,'b' AS b,'c' AS c FROM dual UNION
                        SELECT 'k' AS a,'l' AS b,'n' AS c FROM dual UNION
                        SELECT 'x' AS a,'y' AS b,'z' AS c FROM dual);


CREATE TABLE exampl2 AS (SELECT 'a' AS a,'b' AS b,'_' AS c FROM dual UNION
                        SELECT 'k' AS a,'l' AS b,'_' AS c FROM dual UNION
                        SELECT 'x' AS a,'y' AS b,'_' AS c FROM dual); */                       

BEGIN
  FOR c1 IN (SELECT *
               FROM exampl1)
  LOOP
    UPDATE exampl2 t2
       SET t2.c = c1.c
     WHERE t2.a = c1.a
       AND t2.b = c1.b;
  END LOOP;
END;
```